# Why does $\langle \chi | {(S_z^{(1)}}^2 |\chi \rangle = 2\langle \chi | \frac{\hbar ^2}{4} |\chi \rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

I'm struggling to understand the solution of an exercise and haven't found a similar example on the site so I think this could be of use to a broader audience.

---

We consider the two electrons in a Helium atom with the spin state:
$|\chi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow_z \rangle_1 |\downarrow_z \rangle_2 + |\downarrow_z \rangle_1 |\uparrow_z \rangle_2)$

The total spin in the $z-$ direction is $S_z=S_z^{(1)} + S_z^{(2)}$. Then:  $$\langle \hat{S}_z^2 \rangle = \langle \chi | (S_z^{(1)} + S_z^{(2)})^2 |\chi \rangle = \langle \chi | {(S_z^{(1)}}^2 |\chi \rangle + \langle \chi | S_z^{(1)} S_z^{(2)} |\chi \rangle + \langle \chi | S_z^{(2)} S_z^{(1)} |\chi \rangle + \langle \chi | {(S_z^{(2)}}^2 |\chi \rangle$$

$$= 2\langle \chi | \frac{\hbar ^2}{4} |\chi \rangle + 2\langle \chi | \frac{- \hbar ^2}{4} |\chi \rangle + 2\langle \chi | \frac{- \hbar ^2}{4} |\chi \rangle + 2\langle \chi | \frac{\hbar ^2}{4} |\chi \rangle = 0$$

---

I know that $S_z |\pm \rangle = \pm \frac{\hbar}{2} |\pm \rangle$

May I ask you why there is a $2$ in front of $2\langle \chi | \frac{\hbar ^2}{4} |\chi \rangle$ ? I mean, why is  $\langle \chi | {(S_z^{(1)}}^2 |\chi \rangle $ equal to two times $ \langle \chi | \frac{\hbar ^2}{4} |\chi \rangle$ ? Is it because we have a spin state with two electrons instead of one ?

---

I googled but did not find an answer. (But if it should be trivial, you could redirect me to a website that explains that, that would also work and I would delete my question in that case).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There shouldn’t be a 2.

${\textbf S_{1z}}^2|\chi\rangle={\textbf S_{1z}}^2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+ \frac1{\sqrt2} |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle \right)$

$= \frac1{\sqrt2}\left({\textbf S_{1z}}^2 |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+ {\textbf S_{1z}}^2 |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle \right)$

$= \frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left(\frac\hbar{2}\right)^2 |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+ \left(\frac\hbar{2}\right)^2 |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle \right)$

$= \left(\frac\hbar{2}\right)^2|\chi\rangle$